# preg match with html tag mailto

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-match

I have below code and I want to catch a value that starts with ** Data Contact: **  because I need find email addresses in text.

My code worked when it didin't  have html but I don't know how to change regex in preg match which it will be work in html tag.

```php
$text = 'Some text  Some text 

<a href="mailto:lol@gmail.eu">lol@gmail.eu</a><br />

Data Contact: <a href="mailto:atest@gmail.sbr">atest@gmail.com</a>, <a href="mailto:test@op.eu">test@op.eu</a><br />
<a href="mailto:ag@gmail.eu">ag@gmail.eu</a><br />

Some text  Some text  Some text';

preg_match_all("/Data Contact: +[\._a-zA-Z0-9-]+@[\._a-zA-Z0-9-]+/i", $text, $matches);

foreach($matches[0] as $val){
    
    echo  str_replace("Data Contact:", "",$val);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could see two possible approaches to this issue:

```
<?php
$text = 'Some text  Some text 

Data Contact: <a href="mailto:atest@gmail.sbr">atest@gmail.com</a>, <a href="mailto:test@op.eu">test@op.eu</a><br />
<a href="mailto:ag@gmail.eu">ag@gmail.eu</a><br />

Some text  Some text  Some text';
preg_match_all("/Data Contact: +\K[-.\w]+@[-.\w]+/i", strip_tags($text), $matches);
foreach($matches[0] as $val){
    echo $val;
}
```

which seems to match the question's description. We strip HTML context then pull the email after `Data Contact:`.

Alternatively an HTML parser could be used to pull each link with a `mailto:` context, this matches the question's title:

```
$text = 'Some text  Some text 

Data Contact: <a href="mailto:atest@gmail.sbr">atest@gmail.com</a>, <a href="mailto:test@op.eu">test@op.eu</a><br />
<a href="mailto:ag@gmail.eu">ag@gmail.eu</a><br />

Some text  Some text  Some text';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($text);
$links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach($links as $link){
    $href = $link->getAttribute('href');
    if(strpos($href, 'mailto:') !== FALSE){
        echo str_replace('mailto:', '', $href);
    }
}
```

Update, for updated requirement:

```
<?php
$text = 'Some text  Some text 

Data Contact: <a href="mailto:atest@gmail.sbr">atest@gmail.com</a>, <a href="mailto:test@op.eu">test@op.eu</a><br />
<a href="mailto:ag@gmail.eu">ag@gmail.eu</a><br />

Some text  Some text  Some text';
$emails = preg_replace_callback("/.*Data Contact: +.*/is", function($match){
    preg_match_all('/mailto:\K[-.\w]+@[-.\w]+/', $match[0], $matches);
    $emails = '';
    foreach($matches[0] as $email){
        $emails .= $email . PHP_EOL;
    }
    return $emails;
}, $text);
echo $emails;
```

Find the `Data Contact:` first, then pull each `mailto:` with an email matching value.

Comment: I used your first code and it's works but I have to changed regex to `preg_match_all("/Data Contact: +\K[-.\w]+@[-.\w].+/i", strip_tags($ticket['message']), $matches);` because your script show only one e-mail adresses.`

I still have problem. For example if I will  have five e-mail adress and two e-maills will in new line. Skrypt doesn't show this two e-mails

Comment: What do you think about this regex "/Data Contact: +\K[-.\w]+@[-.\w].+\s[-.\w]+@[-.\w].+\s[-.\w]+@[-.\w].+/i" ?

Comment: @inomi13 That would be finite. See updated answer, I think that will be more dynamic/scalable.

Comment: Your job is great and your code works but has one problem. The code finds any emails, but I just need to find the emails that start with the Contact Details row. I chnaged regex and works. What do your think about this `"/((Data Contact: +\K[-.\w]+@[-.\w].*)(\n(?=[-.\w]+@[-.\w]).*|.))/"`

Comment: It currently looks for `Data Contact:` then continues to the end of the string. Is there a rule for when you don't want emails after `Data Contact:`?

Comment: I receive e-mail forms with have emails addresses after name Data Contact. I found solution my problem so I close this post. Again thanks for help :)